# SQLite3 Queries

Tags: python, sqlite

I am looking to fetch employee shift details (for 7 days) which works well ; however, the each row ends with ",". I am looking to delete "," so that I can copy those results to tkinter entry boxes.

```
def showRecord():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("C:\Projects\Advisor Roster Swap\employee.db")
    connection.text_factory = sqlite3.OptimizedUnicode
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT "Scheduled Shift" FROM employee_details WHERE Ecode = "5568328"''')
    items = cursor.fetchall()
    print(items)
    connection.close()
```

The result looks like : [('WO',), ('10:30 - 19:30',), ('10:30 - 19:30',), ('10:30 - 19:30',), ('10:30 - 19:30',), ('10:30 - 19:30',), ('WO',)]

I need to delete the extra ",". Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items` is a list of tuples, the comma is only shown when printing it. If you want to get the column value for the `n`th row, `items[n - 1]` will give you a tuple containing just the value: `("WO",)`. To then get the value in the tuple use `items[n - 1][0]`. You can wrap this in to a comprehension:

```py
items = [i[0] for i in items]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps a lot.
Any idea how to copy above results (7 results) in 7 different tkinter entry boxes I have ?
I need a view of shifts for an employee

Comment: Great! If my respone answered your question, please click the check mark next to it! And please create a new question for your next issue.